# Trackpoint not working at all on Lenovo t570 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lenovo

I have just acquired a clean Lenovo T570, and the first thing I always do is install Ubuntu.

The Trackpad is working fine in Ubuntu, but the Trackpoint (the red nubby joystick mouse between the G, H, and B keys) does not seem to be recognized at all, and the three associated buttons do not seem to do anything. I dislike the touchpad, strongly in favor of the TrackPoint, so this is an issue for me. (The Trackpoint is part of why I choose Lenovo laptops. It has worked without issue on T510 and T430 models.)

Where would I start troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

Edits:
I have tried the following, with results as shown:

```bsh
barry@T570:~$ find /sys/devices/platform/i8042 -name name | xargs grep -Fl TrackPoint | set 's/\/input\/input[0-9]*\/name$//'
barry@T570:~$ xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
barry@T570:~$
```

Thus, there seems to be no TrackPoint device recognized as present. That said, the center button *does* paste from the clipboard into the terminal window as I would expect it to.

Comment: I wish I had this wonderful Trackpoint (the best invention IBM ever did) - OK, you may have the same problem as many other Laptop users: Your device is(!) recognised but disabled because tablet mode is enabled. Not easy to fix. Most likely one kernel module is blocking. So it is not the lack but the over provision of drivers.

Comment: Use the same tips others tried - watch out for this f#$@* tablet mode.  You may do experiments if there is a single situation when the trackpoint does work (like resume after suspend). This would point to blocking issue. Load new modules like i2c-hid for touchpads, find out which kernel modules should be there. And try to block wrong ones that are related to pointing devices. Use lshw and lsmod . Good luck, I do not have better advice. Always takes me days or weeks to find these things but got them Laptops all working ;-)

Comment: @BarryTice did you find a solution to this? Similar issue on the T490

Comment: Andrew, it turns out that the clean T570 I had picked up from eBay had faulty hardware. I tried installing Windows on it, and the trackpad didn't work with that, either. I eventually sent it back to the seller and got my money back.

Sorry I don't have an answer for you. Good luck!